# get most frequent two consecutive numbers

Tags: python, numpy

```
import itertools, numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,2,3,6,7]
c = [5,2,3,8,9]
```

get most frequent numbers:

```
data = np.array([a,b,c]).flatten()
print (data)

values, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)

for value, frequency in zip(values, counts):
    print (value, frequency)
```

How can I get most frequent two consecutive numbers?
Answer is [2,3].
But how to get it by program?

Comment: What does your current attempt give you?

Comment: Your description would benefit from some more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and iterate over `data` in consecutive pairs:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,2,3,6,7]
c = [5,2,3,8,9]

data = np.array([a,b,c]).flatten()

c = Counter(zip(data, data[1:]))
print(c.most_common(1))
# [((2, 3), 3)]
```

telling you that `(2, 3)` occurred 3 times.

---

a bit more detail:

```
data[1:]
```

is your `data` without its first element.

```
zip(data, data[1:])
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is then used to generate the consecutive pairs (as `tuples`)

```
(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5), (5, 2), (2, 3), ...
```

the `Counter` then just counts how many times the appear and stores them `dict`-like:

```
Counter({(2, 3): 3, (5, 2): 2, (1, 2): 1, (3, 4): 1, (4, 5): 1, (5, 5): 1, (3, 6): 1,
         (6, 7): 1, (7, 5): 1, (3, 8): 1, (8, 9): 1})
```

---

update: if you do not want pairs from different list, you can do this:

```
data = (a, b, c)

c = Counter()
for d in data:
    c.update(zip(d, d[1:]))
print(c)
```

or directly:

```
c = Counter(pair for d in data for pair in zip(d, d[1:]))
```

Comment: could you explain me what `c = Counter(zip(data, data[1:]))` is doing?

Comment: ok, thanks, accepted. by the way, can it be modified for the case 3 consecutive numbers?

Comment: Okay. However I do not want use `(5, 5)` as two consecutive numbers as they are in two different lists (a and b)

Comment: I think, this function should be modified `zip(data, data[1:])` to omit consecutive from different lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` as suggested by @hiro protagonist, but since you want to treat a one row at a time, you have to apply it along rows.

```
from collections import Counter
```

Apply along rows using numpy:

```
data = np.array([a,b,c])

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: Counter(zip(x, x[1:])), 1, data).sum().most_common(1)
[((2, 3), 3)]
```

Or, if using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([a,b,c])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, apply Counter along rows:

```
df.apply(lambda x: Counter(zip(x, x[1:])), axis = 1).sum().most_common(1)

[((2, 3), 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use .sum()?

Comment: @skydriver see the output of `
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: Counter(zip(x, x[1:])), 1, data)`